# Parsing TextView for email address

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I am writing a simple brochure app. I have text in a textview that has email addresses in it.

```
<string name="wbl_contacts">
<p><strong>CONTACT</strong></p>
<p>
  <strong>Where you can find us</strong>
  1525 Newton St NW
  Washington D.C., DC 20010
202.667.1192
  For current listing of class schedule at each of our sites, e-mail <a href="mailto:enroll@wblinc.org.">enroll@wblinc.org</a>
  To learn about volunteer opportunities e-mail <a href="mailto:volunteer@wblinc.org">volunteer@wblinc.org</a>
  To submit your resume for internship consideration e-mail <a href="mailto:intern@wblinc.org">intern@wblinc.org</a>
  To submit work for consideration for publication in the WBL journal email <a href="mailto:submissions@wblinc.org">submissions@wblinc.org</a>
  All other questions can be directed to <a href="mailto:info@wblinc.org">info@wblinc.org</a>
or call us at 202-667-1192 </p>
    </string>
```

I am attempting to use the Intent class to extra the mail applications like so:

```
//setting textviews
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        //tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.wbl_contacts)));

        tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //This will open an email client.  Find a way to use this code
                //to open all email address on any android app page
                Intent emailintent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailintent.setType("text/html");
                emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {tv1.getText().toString()});
                emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                emailintent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent, "Send mail..."));
            }
            });
```

When I run my app, it seems as if the entire TextView is clickable even though the email links all are highlighed as if they are linkable....a little lost.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you shouldn't use Intent for that kind of behaviour. Instead you should linkify your TextView. You can read more about linkify [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html).

You would do something like following:

```
Linkify.addLinks(tv1 , Linkify.ALL);
```

Or if you only had the email addresses and not href:

```
Linkify.addLinks(tv1 , Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
```

**Edit extra answer**:

Your using HTML syntax instead of regular text with emails in it, so maybe you should use:

```
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("your string");
```

Not all HTML tags are supported by Android but a list of supported HTML tags can be found [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.dk/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html).

Comment: nope didnt work for me... when I click any of the email addresses, its acts as if it it linking the entire text and no email apps pop up...

Comment: @that_developer Added a new answer

Comment: still nothing...  The links highlighted but when clicked, it is the entire tire textview that is linked....   this frustrating lol

Comment: @that_developer please remove the click listener and make sure the textview don't have clickable=true.

Comment: here is my xml: '<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize = "15sp"
        android:autoLink = "email"
        android:text="@string/wbl_contacts" />'

Comment: here is my java: 'protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
  
  //setting textviews
  tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
  //tv1.setText(R.string.wbl_contacts);
  tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.wbl_contacts)));
  Linkify.addLinks(tv1 , Linkify.ALL);
  
    // tv1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  //tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.wbl_contacts))); 
  loadDoc();
 }'

Comment: @that_developer try to use only one. Linkify or from HTML. If neighter works you'll have to split it into several textviews.

Comment: I discover the issue was with a private function call i had the loadDoc().  It calls this --> tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod() for which I thought I needed for scrolling capabilites of text on a view.  Now that I have found this.  I know need a way to captured the email address is clicked so that I may use the intent class to insert it into an email androi app like gmail or outlook or is that not necessary and it should automatically give me the option when an email address is clicked?

Comment: @that_developer with the options I've posted that happens automatically. Just remember to test on a phone where multiple options are possible or it will just default to one.

Comment: ah ok thanks and as I read your response I just figured that out after also going through the APIDemos for Link.  The only thing I an now trying to figure out is how to **not** have it populate all of the text in the textview instead of just the email address in the "To:" portion of whatever email app I choose after I have clicked the email address.